# Numeric padding in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, decimal, padding

is there a way I can format a numeric decimal number to a 12 digit ?

I have to integrate the project with a payment gateway and the requirement says that

> The amount will have to be padded with "0" from the left and include no decimal point.
>   Ex : 1 = 000000000100 or 1.5 = 000000000150

So far, I have Convert.ToDecimal(amount).ToString().PadLeft(12, '0');

but this gives me 000000000015. I tried to .PadRight also but that doesn't give out the result.

Thank you

Comment: what should be output for numbers with more decimal. like `1.234` ?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Thank you for your answer! It works very well. We only count 2 decimals, so it shouldn't be a problem at all :)

Answer (score 3):

Just multiply your number by 100.

```
Convert.ToDecimal(amount*100).ToString().PadLeft(12, '0')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also give this a try.

```
Convert.ToDecimal(amount).ToString("0000000000.00").Replace(".", "");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works very well. Your answer fits my case perfectly as I try assigning amount = 1.5m and it gives out exactly 000000000150. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

and the
- [Decimal("D") Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_2) (pads zeroes);
- same page, [code sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_11).

```
int value; 

value = 12345;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("D"));
// Displays 12345
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("D8"));
// Displays 00012345
```

Comment: use with 'multiply by 100' (below), if needed.